# Where should I put a DLL that is cross-compiled from source?

Tags: c, windows, dll, directory, cross-compiling

I really want to use the [libpostal](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal) library as part of my Java application via the [jpostal](https://github.com/openvenues/jpostal) binding. While I can work around the fact that jpostal uses Gradle instead of Maven, I'm not sure where to proceed after I've cross compiled a libpostal DLL using a Linux machine.

According [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38230041/what-is-the-equivalent-of-usr-lib-on-windows), the process of installing a DLL on Windows is very convoluted.

If anyone has good idea as to where I can put the DLL so that my Java application using jpostal can find it, please tell me.

P.S: My Java application will run on a CentOS machine in production but for development, testing, and demoing I'm using my laptop and desktop which run Windows. Of course if I can't get libpostal to work on Windows, then I can always go the virtual machine route.

Comment: Probably you don't need to *install* anything, you just have to take care your dll and it's dependencies are in the dll search path (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx). I don't know Java, but see point 1 and 2 in the link: have you tried just putting the dll next to the main executable?

Comment: Java applications are usually packaged as JAR or WAR files, depending on whether the application is a web app or not.

Comment: The only "executable" that I'm aware of is the Java virtual machine.

Comment: If the VM sets the current working directory to the JAR path it should find dlls there. Or apparently in java.library.path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092200/how-to-fix-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-find-dependent-libraries-in-a-jni-pro